# Write Range Values from an excel file to another excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have the following code and I am trying to copy certain Range values from one Excel file to another.

I have managed to select the range from the first excel, but it does not "paste" it where I've selected the range to.

In this example, it copies it to the first cells in the second excel.

Could anyone help please?

Thank you!

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"Excel.xlsx", 1);
            Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[9];
            Workbook workbook1 = application.Workbooks.Open(@"Excel2.xlsx", 1);
            Worksheet xlWorksheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook1.Sheets[1];
            Range range1 = xlWorksheet.get_Range("C1", "C5");
            object[,] valueArray = (object[,])range1.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
            Range range2 = xlWorksheet1.get_Range("F1", "F5");
            object[,] valueArray2 = (object[,])range2.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
                        
            for (int i = 2; i <= valueArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= valueArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k <= valueArray2.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 1; l <= valueArray2.GetLength(1); l++)
                        {
                            valueArray2[i,j] = valueArray[i, j].ToString();
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            workbook1.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            workbook1.Close();
            application.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new 
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
         Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Excel.xlsx", 1);
         Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
         Workbook workbook1 = application.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Excel2.xlsx", 1);
         Worksheet xlWorksheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook1.Sheets[1];
         Range range1 = xlWorksheet.get_Range("C1", "C5");
         Range range2 = xlWorksheet1.get_Range("F1", "F5");
         range1.Copy(range2);
         workbook1.Save();
         workbook.Save();
         workbook.Close();
         workbook1.Close();
         application.Quit();
```

Thank you!